# Getting values, by reflection, of inner objects from a class

Tags: c#, reflection

Heys, guys!
I'm trying to get values from my objects by reflection, buy I have a problem: I can get a value from the base object, but I can't get values from inner objects, like this:

```
public class Employee
{
   public long EmployeeID { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public DateTime EmployeeAdmissionDate { get; set; }
   public Person EmployeePerson { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public long PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PersonBirthday { get; set; }
}

private static void GetDTOProperties(IDictionary<string, object> dicProperties, Type objectToSerialize)
    {
        Type typeOfObject = objectToSerialize is Type ? objectToSerialize as Type : objectToSerialize.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeOfObject.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (!property.PropertyType.IsClass || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                dicProperties.Add(string.Format("{0}_{1}", property.DeclaringType.Name.ToLower(), property.Name.ToLower()), property.GetValue(typeOfObject, null));
            else
                GetDTOProperties(dicProperties, property.PropertyType);
        }
    }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee objEmployee = new Employee();
    objEmployee.EmployeeID = 1;
    objEmployee.EmployeeNumber = 457435;
    objEmployee.EmployeeAdmissionDate = DateTime.Now;
    objEmployee.EmployeePerson = new EmployeePerson();

    objEmployee.EmployeePerson.PersonID = 123;
    objEmployee.EmployeePerson.PersonName = "Kiwanax";
    objEmployee.EmployeePerson.PersonBirthday = DateTime.Now;

    IDictionary<string, object> dicProperties= new Dictionary<string, object>();
    GetDTOProperties(dicPropriedades, objEntidadeAluno.GetType());
    foreach (string m in dicProperties.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine(m + " - " + dicProperties[m]);

    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The base values I can get, but the values of "Person" inner object I can't. Anyone has idea? Thanks!!

Comment: if you use Java as a programmer language, you should rename the first letter of methods name to lower case letter. Properbly that thing can solve your problem.

Comment: The above is not Java. I guess it's C#. If so, it should be re-tagged as such.

Comment: AFAIK this is entirely written in `C#` I don't see how you want to use `Java`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I fixed that error.

Comment: Strange - it worked as excepted for me - I`ve got all properties (except Employee.EmployeePerson - because you don`t count this property, but you can add it to dictionary as well). So only problem - is that you are trying to get property values, whereas you have only types - but not objects

Answer (score 1):

You can update your method like this:

```
private static void GetDTOProperties(IDictionary<string, object> dicProperties, object objectToSerialize)
{
   Type typeOfObject = objectToSerialize is Type ? objectToSerialize as Type : objectToSerialize.GetType();
   PropertyInfo[] properties = typeOfObject.GetProperties();
   foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
   {
      object val = objectToSerialize is Type ? property.PropertyType : property.GetValue(objectToSerialize, null);
      if (!property.PropertyType.IsClass || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
      {
         dicProperties.Add(string.Format("{0}_{1}", property.DeclaringType.Name.ToLower(), property.Name.ToLower()), val);                    
      }
      else
         GetDTOProperties(dicProperties, val);
   }
}
```

So there wont ba any problems with objects and you can send actual objects to that method. If you send type of object, than you will get Types as Values in dictionary

Comment: Thanks, Jleru, buy I don't want the type of the objects, but the values inside them.

Comment: Than call that method with objects, like GetDTOProperties(dicPropriedades, objEntidadeAluno);